# NEMA 1 load center, recessed in wall, open to a covered porch

Tags: electrical

Is it acceptable to mount a NEMA 1 Load Center, recessed in wall, open toward covered porch?

Comment: Do you get sideways rain where you're at?  Also, are you replacing an existing loadcenter, or installing a new panel where none was previously present?

Comment: Really if there is no requirement for a wet location how is this different?